# Best way to cut a pineapple ring?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, applications

I like to prepare pineapples by first cutting it into rounds and then slicing off the skin with a roast beef slicer. This leaves me with a hexagon "ring" around a circular core:

[image: A pineapple ring]

I then don't want to dirty another knife to core it, so I just reuse the beef slicer. But it's too big for precise cuts, so I have to cut all the way across the ring. Normally a cut a small square around the core, like this:

[image: Four cuts around a ring]

The problem is this leaves me with unequal pieces— the first piece is much bigger and the fourth piece is much smaller. How can I make N cuts, each across the entire remaining core, so that I'm left with a set of pieces that are as close in area to each other as possible? I don't care about them having the same *shape*, just that they have the same area. N doesn't have to be 4, though I'd really prefer to keep it under 6 or so. Some waste around the core is ok.

Comment: I've thought about this a lot myself! Practically, my solution is to cut piece number 1 in half after having separated it from the core.

Comment: If the piece have area $p_1,\cdots,p_n$ and the left over around the core has area $q$, then one could devise a function of the $p_j$ which is lesser when they are more equal to each other, and also depended on $q$ and ws lesser for smaller $q.$ Then your answer seems like it would depend on how the suggested "penalty funcion" is set up. Is this the idea?

Comment: You'd need to state your optimization function. Some improvements could be: 1/ Having only 3 slices, with the 3rd at $45^\circ$, resulting in more even areas, though there's a lot of wastage. 2/ moving slices 2 and 3 anticlockwise slightly to increase area 4. We could even make areas 2,3, 4 equal. There's a bit more wastage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For four equal pieces in four cuts you could try something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

May be this idea helps if the cut around the ring needs not to be square. Areas of 1, 2 , 4 and 5 are equal. also are areas of 3 and 6.

Comment: 3 and 6 require two cuts for the bit around the ring though :D